# Huawei bought in China, can't access Google Play (g510 t8951)

Tags: google-play-store, rooting, huawei

I bought this huawei cellphone in China and I can't access the google store. I can access some apps through Baidu Store but then some doesn't work because I don't have Google Play Service. I've tried installing it through Baidu Store, it just crashes, and through "Google downloader" (an app on baidu) and now Google Play launches but doesn't connect (no connection).

I don't know what to do anymore, any idea?

I'm willing to root etc... but there is no thread explaining how for my phone.

Comment: Might have to use stronger google-fu and XDA to see if there's a means to do so, usually, [OneClick Root](http://www.oneclickroot.com/) might do the job - its worth a try,

Comment: Try rooting, installing a custom recovery and then finding an English ROM to flash on XDA or some such place. There'll be guides on Google.

Comment: unfortunately they're all in chinese, and I can't find a way to root my phone

Comment: Not tried it but [link](http://theunlockr.com/2013/07/30/how-to-root-the-huawei-ascend-g510/) for root

Comment: I have rooted the phone thanks to baidu root. Still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Three steps to regain full control over your phone,

1. Root your phone. There are dozens of rooting software out there. Last I used for a Huawei phone was Kingo Root, did the job quite well. Note: This might involve factory reset.
2. Install custom recovery. It might be tricky to learn which version will work with your phone. XDA should help. Otherwise trial and error. Note: This step might be optional, depending on your ROM.
3. Install GApps using (custom) recovery. There are plenty of different GApps packages out there, just google it. I normally go for the smallest GApps package, with just Play services and Play store. All other Google apps can be downloaded from the Play store later. Note: Not all GApps "editions" work with all ROMs, you will also need to use trial and error method.

ALTERNATIVE METHOD:

Check manufacturer's website for a non-Chinese ROM version. It will almost certainly have a working Play store. You should be able to flash it easily without rooting the phone.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can flash a Google Apps package, also known as Gapps.
This adds Play Store to your apps.
As for Google being blocked in China, try any VPN solution, such as Hotspot Shield.

Answer (score -1):

you might install mobogenie .it gives u one -click root feature.so you may root that ways.and moreover huawei phones have a large range and most of them are not known.so either buy a well known product or go for samsung products

Answer (score -1):

do NOT root or do any other huge thing,
you just need a VPN 
so download a VPN in your computer, and download play store in your computer aslo,
connect your phone to your computer and install both,

that is it, i was in a town close to Shanghai and i had the same problem, it solved so easily,